# How to concat two dataframes with interleaved rows sorted by a column of the first dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have two dataframes:

```
>> df1

   X  Y  avg id
   f  g  30   3
   a  b  20   1
   d  e  10   2


>> df2

   X  Y  avg id
   D  E  10   2 
   A  B  0    1
   F  G  20   3
```

`df1` is sorted by `avg` column. I want to concat them so that put corresponding rows of second `dataframe` under the row of first `dataframe` without changing the order:

```
   X  Y  avg id
   f  g  30   3
   F  G  20   3
   a  b  20   1
   A  B  0    1
   d  e  10   2
   D  E  10   2
```

I tried `pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index().reset_index()` but it doesnt' produce my desire output

Comment: You seem to have the DF sorted by **id** so why not do that after **concat**

Comment: @user19077881 I explicitly wrote that I want them be sorted based on avg from df1, the other things are coincidence, id is irrelevant here. I modified the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ordered [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) for possible sorting after `concat` by `df1.id` values:

```
out = (pd.concat([df1, df2])
         .assign(id = lambda x: pd.Categorical(x['id'], categories=df1['id'].unique()))
         .sort_values('id', ignore_index=True))
print (out)
   X  Y  avg id
0  f  g   30  3
1  F  G   20  3
2  a  b   20  1
3  A  B    0  1
4  d  e   10  2
5  D  E   10  2
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved it using a loop:

```
import pandas as pd

# Your dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['f', 'a', 'd'],
                    'Y': ['g', 'b', 'e'],
                    'avg': [30, 20, 10],
                    'id': [3, 1, 2]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['D', 'A', 'F'],
                    'Y': ['E', 'B', 'G'],
                    'avg': [10, 0, 20],
                    'id': [2, 1, 3]})

# Initialize an empty list to store rows
data = []

# Iterate through the rows of df1
for _, row1 in df1.iterrows():
    data.append(row1.to_dict())
    # Find the corresponding row in df2 based on 'id'
    row2 = df2[df2['id'] == row1['id']].to_dict('records')[0]
    data.append(row2)

# Create a new dataframe from the list of rows
result_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(result_df)
```